# Finding the Mode of a Probability Distribution Function

Tags: probability-distributions

If I have a pdf represented by the following function:

$$f(x) = \dfrac{3(x+x^2)}{14}  $$ from $0<x<2$. I know I must look for the maximum value $f(x)$ achieves and the mode will be the $x$ value associated with it. Is this a case where there is no mode, which is my suspicion?

Comment: The function is increasing on the interval $[0,2]$ so its maximum value is at $x=2$. Do you know the definition of **mode** for a continuous pdf? If not, try Google.

Comment: Since 2 is not included though would this mean there is no mode? I understand that it is increasing the entire interval.

Comment: By pdf do you mean probability *density* function or probability *distribution* function? I ask because the second meaning is ambiguous, since it can mean *cumulative* distribution function. Since you are using lower case $f$ I assume you mean probability *density* function. For a continuous variable $X$, the probability that $X$ actually equals the mode is always $0$, so I see no reason that the mode in this case would not be $2$.